# What is wrong with getting response via WSDL in ZF2

Tags: wsdl, zend-framework2, soap-client

I'm trying to execute this:

```
    $client = new \Zend\Soap\Client("http://www.granica.gov.pl/Services/czasyService/granica.wsdl");

    $obj = new \stdClass();
    $obj->jednostka = 'terespol';
    $obj->rok = '2014';
    $obj->miesiac = '7';
    $obj->dzien = '11';
    $obj->godzina = '0';
    $client->getCzasy($obj);
```

and I get an error "Method Not Implemented".

What am I doing wrong? When I delete one of the $obj params - for example "rok" i get error: "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'rok' property"

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I found an answer. Changing soap version helped to get result. Correct code should be like this:

```
$client = new \Zend\Soap\Client("http://www.granica.gov.pl/Services/czasyService/granica.wsdl",  array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
));

$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->jednostka = 'terespol';
$obj->rok = '2014';
$obj->miesiac = '7';
$obj->dzien = '11';
$obj->godzina = '0';
$client->getCzasy($obj);
```